# How to resolve issue :: file_get_contents(http://localhost:8085/assets/data/test.txt): Failed to open stream: HTTP request failed

Tags: rest, codeigniter, file-get-contents

By using CodeIgniter 4 framework, I've developed **RESTful api** and there I need to access file (.json and .txt) to get content. But not able to access php inbuilt function file_get_contents().
For more details, pls check attached screenshot API_curl_file_get_content_error.PNG
[image]

And test.txt file is also accessible with same file path. For more details pls check screenshot Input-txt-file-content.png
[image]

**NOTE :** 1) test.txt file and respective directories have full permission.
2) *Development environment :*
<---->Apache/2.4.47 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1k PHP/8.1.2
<---->Database client version: libmysql - mysqlnd 8.1.2
<---->PHP version: 8.1.2
<---->**CodeIgniter 4**

###### Product.php (*index* method)

```php
<?php

namespace App\Controllers;
use CodeIgniter\RESTful\ResourceController;

class Product extends ResourceController
{
    use \CodeIgniter\API\ResponseTrait;

    public function index()
    {
        helper("filesystem");
        ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);

        $data['msg'] = "Product Index wizard";
        $data['status'] = 200;
        $file_path = base_url() . '/assets/data/test.txt';   // Read JSON
        $json = file_get_contents($file_path, true);
        $json_data = json_decode($json, true);

        return $this->respond($data);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### Explanation:

Remember that "http://localhost:8085/" most likely points to the ***document root*** of the project, which is usually the `/public` path. So, unless the "*assets*" folder resides in the `/public` path, `file_get_contents("http://localhost:8085/assets/data/test.txt");` will fail to find the requested server resource.

##### Solution:

Since your file resource (*test.txt*) is on the local filesystem,

Instead of:

```php
file_get_contents("http://localhost:8085/assets/data/test.txt");
```

Use this:
[constant `ROOTPATH`](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/common_functions.html?highlight=apppath#ROOTPATH)

> The path to the project root directory. Just above [APPPATH](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/common_functions.html?highlight=apppath#APPPATH).

```php
file_get_contents(ROOTPATH . "assets/data/test.txt");
```

##### Addendum:

I believe you also forgot to add the `$json_data` output to the returned `$data` variable in the `Product::index` resource controller method.